# Complex Integration for polar coordinates

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

I need to find $\int_{\gamma} |z|^2dz$ for $\gamma[0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ with $\gamma(t)=r(\cos(2\pi t)+i\sin(2 \pi t)) $. I will use the formula:
$$
\int_{\gamma}f(z)dz=\int_0^1f(\gamma(t))\gamma'(t)dt
$$
and using that for $z=x+iy$ it is $|z|=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ we get $|z|^2=x^2+y^2$. First I tought about using Eulers formula for $r(\cos(2\pi t)+i\sin(2 \pi t))$ but it seems that this can be done much easier, tough not quite sure because it seems too easy. So:
$$
|r\cos(2\pi t)+r i\sin(2 \pi t))|^2=r^2\cos^2(2\pi t)+r^2\sin^2(2\pi t)=r^2(\cos^2(2\pi t)+\sin^2(2\pi t)) = r^2
$$
since $\cos^2(2\pi t)+\sin^2(2\pi t)=1$.
So  we get
$$
\int_{\gamma}f(z)dz=\int_0^1f(\gamma(t))\gamma'(t)dt = \int_0^1r^2\gamma'(t)dt=r^2\int_0^1\gamma'(t)dt = r^2[\gamma(t)]_0^1 = r^2(r(\cos(2\pi)+i\sin(2 \pi))-r(\cos(0)+i\sin(0)))=r^2(r(1+0)-r(1+0))=r^2(r-r)= 0
$$
Does this make sense and if not, where ist the mistake? Thank you guys in advanc!

Comment: You're good. That's correct. Do you understand perhaps the *point* of the exercise?

Comment: No, unfortunatly not really...

Comment: I think this exercise highlights the difference between real and complex integration. The element of integration $dz$ is 'vectorial' in nature, so even though your integrand is eveywhere strictly positive (and in fact constant), the 'vectorial summation' of the elements $dz$ is $0$.

Comment: Do you know how to justify that $\int_0^1\gamma'(t)dt = \left.\gamma(t)\right|_0^1$? You cannot just claim the fundamental theorem of calculus directly, since that involves real functions, not complex. It is not hard at all to justify, but make sure that you know what that justification is instead of just assuming it is true.